# append parameter into string with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm generating fields dynamically but I need to add a id in the middle of the string that will be the input.

```
 var id = uid();
 $(wrapper).after('<div> <input class="form-control" type="text"name="mytext[]"/>').after('<a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');
```

But it only works if the `after` is used in the final of enclose tag.

Comment: why not `$(wrapper).after('<div> <input class="form-control" value="'+id+'" type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved here:

```
$(wrapper).after('<div> <input class="form-control" value="'+id+'" type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');
```